# Can every program be turned into a quine?

Tags: computability

Given a program $P$ which takes a binary string as input, can one always (effectively) construct a program $P'$ such that $P'(0x)$ runs $P(x)$ and $P'(1x)$ outputs the source code of $P'$? I didn't find anything with some googling, but it seems like the kind of thing that could be known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem). Let $F(e)$ be the function that on input $0x$ returns $P(x)$ and on input $1x$ returns $e$. A fixed point $\varphi_e = \varphi_{F(e)}$ is what you're looking for.

If you're interested in how this quine is constructed, take a look at the proof, for example [here](http://saadquader.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/kleenes-recursion-theorem/).